# Cannot resolve BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Android Studio says it cannot resolve bottomnavigationview in my code. All BottomNavigationView text is red. Also, when I go to the xml layout page, instead of showing the bottom navigation view icons it shows 'android...BottomNavigationView' in a grey box. But when I run the app on my device, I see the icons. (Though it's a little squished)

I've tried rebuilding and cleaning the app code. I had this problem before, a few days ago, so I deleted the file and started over, and the bottom navigation problem was fine. But then whenever I quit android studio and reopen it, it gives me the issue.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_list:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_list);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_done:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_done);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_categories:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_categories);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

I created this activity with the preset Bottom Navigation activity so I haven't tinkered with any code yet apart from changing the icons and icon names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

In your app build.gradle file in dependencies tab add below line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Here 26.1.0 is library version instead of this add your library version and Sync Project.

Answer (score 1):

For Androidx Use this library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

And use BottomNavigationView in your layout as below

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
      android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to just re-sync gradle. Hope that's the solution for now.